# Convert signal to db scale

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to convert a signal to db scale. This is done to find the global min and max for pcolormesh later on.

However i don't know if this is the correct way to approach this. The second plot to me doesn't look right...

The raw signal:

[image: signal raw]

and i convert to db scale using np:

```
x = 10 * np.log10(df["FP1-F7"])
```

It looks like:

[image: db converted]

-------------------UPDATE----------------------------------

I have done the following:

```
noverlap = 256 / 2
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7), facecolor='w')
f, Pxx_den = signal.welch(df["FP1-F7"], fs=256, nperseg=256, window='hanning', detrend=False, noverlap=noverlap)

plt.plot(f, Pxx_den)
```

gives me:

[image: welch]

Then i convert it by:

```
Pxx_den_db = 10*np.log10(Pxx_den)
mn = np.min(Pxx_den_db)
mx = np.max(Pxx_den_db)

and use those as the limits in the colorscale:

f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(np.array(df["FP1-F7"][0:2000]), fs=256, nperseg=256, noverlap=int(256*0.95), scaling='density', return_onesided=True)

normalize_color= matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=mn, vmax=mx)
Sxx = 10*np.log10(Sxx)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, cmap='jet', norm=normalize_color)# Plot the result
plt.colorbar(label='Power (dB)')
```

Now my colormesh is using same color scale

[image: spec]

My question is now is there a faster way to compute this min max value of an entire signal?

Comment: What exactly concerns you? "It doesn't look right" is too vague. Note that your signal is partially negative. You cannot apply `log10` to negative numbers. Perhaps you should calculate the magnitude first.

Comment: It is because i want to construct spectrograms and i split the signal into frames of 4 seconds. Then i am using the STFT on each window. I found out that the color density / power of each frequency was way different for each window. So i want to get global min and max value of the signal db and then pass it to the pyplot.pcolormesh norm argument so that all spectrogram has the same scale. So if i understand correctly i should first get the PSD of the entire signal and then convert to db? Then find the min/max of db rescaled psd of the whole signal.

Comment: I am not sure _how_ to do what you want. All I tell is that you cannot `log10` a negative number.

Comment: The decibel is a relative unit of measurement that expresses the ratio of two values of a power or root-power quantity on a logarithmic scale.  What does``` df["FP1-F7"]``` look like?  What values are you using to compute the ratio?

Comment: @DYZ notice that there are gaps in the log plot.  I assume that's where negative values ended up making `np.log10` deliver `nan` results.

Comment: @itprorh66 for audio applications you typically get a ratio by dividing the signal by its limit, positive signal by positive limit and negative signal by negative limit.  All the ratios are thus positive, and the DB values are all negative or zero.